# How can I customize the order of nodes in a sankey diagram using highcharter library in R?

Tags: r, nodes, sankey-diagram, r-highcharter

I am trying to plot a sankey diagram with the highcharter library in R

It is actually quite straightforward to get the plot, but I cannot manage to customize the order of the nodes.

Could someone help me?

```
library(highcharter)
pl<-hchart(data_to_sankey(data), "sankey")
```